# bijection $\{0, 1, \ldots, \binom{|m|}{n}-1\} \longleftrightarrow \binom{m}{n}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

I am attempting to generate random numbers which correspond to states in a game. Say there are $|m|$ squares, and $n$ pieces which can occupy the squares. Then I can have a total of $\binom{|m|}{n}$ states, given the pieces are indistinct.

However, I would like to transform the randomly generated number $\left[0, \binom{|m|}{n}\right)$ into a specific state, and for this I need a bijection $\{0, 1, \ldots, \binom{|m|}{n}-1\}$ $\longleftrightarrow$ $\binom{m}{n}$.

An algorithm that I can think of (that may work) would in essence order the pieces, and place the $i^\text{th}$ piece on the $i^\text{th}$ square to start. Then iterate over the pieces, shifting the rightmost piece right if the square is not occupied. Whenever a piece $p_0$ to the left of any other given pieces $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ is shifted right, then shift $p_1, \ldots p_k$ left as far as possible such that $p_i$ is still on a lesser square than $p_j$.

I would appreciate guidance in any other directions or any simplifications etc!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $m$ is the set of squares and $|m|$ is the number of squares. Can you confirm that? $\qquad$

Comment: You shouldn't keep alternating in and out of MathJax within an expression in mathematical notation. The whole of $\text{“ } \{0, 1, \ldots, \binom{|m|}{n}-1\} \longleftrightarrow \binom{m}{n} \text{ ''}$ should be between just one pair of dollar signs. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: But on the other hand, the first occurrence of $m$ in you posting seems to assume it's a number rather than a set.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hi Michael, sorry for delayed response. Indeed your guess is correct. Thanks for latex advice. Ah yes, that's wrong. I guess I should have used $S$ and $|S|$, and then my opening statement could use $|S|$ as the number of pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the $\binom mn$ possible $n$-element subsets of the $m$ squares, $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ have a piece on the last square, and $\binom{m-1}{n}$ don't.

So you can do the following:

- If there is no piece on the last square, use this algorithm recursively for the arrangement of $n$ pieces on the first $m-1$ squares. This gives you a number between $0$ and $\binom{m-1}{n}-1$.
- If there is a piece on the last square, use this algorithm recursively for the arrangement of $n-1$ pieces on the first $m-1$ squares. This gives you a number between $0$ and $\binom{m-1}{n-1}-1$. Then, add $\binom{m-1}{n}$ to it, getting a number between $\binom{m-1}{n}$ and $\binom mn - 1$.

As a base case for this algorithm, whenever $m=n$ or $n=0$, there is only one possible arrangement, and you should give it the number $0$.

---

Actually, if we look carefully at the recursive algorithm above, we can "unroll" it. Note that we only have one place where we modify the number we get: when the $n^{\text{th}}$ piece is on the $m^{\text{th}}$ square, we add $\binom{m-1}{n}$ to the number. (We can simplify this rule by numbering the squares $0, 1, 2, \dots, m-1$, so that the $m-1$ in $\binom{m-1}{n}$ is the number of the last square.)

So if the squares are numbered $0, 1, 2, \dots, m-1$ and the pieces are located on squares $0 \le m_1 < m_2 < \dots < m_n \le m-1$, then the algorithm above will ultimately produce the value
$$
    \binom{m_1}{1} + \binom{m_2}{2} + \dots + \binom{m_n}{n}
$$
and we can just output that directly. (But without the recursive algorithm, it would be super unclear why that worked.)

Comment: that's genius :)

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand, you're trying to enumerate the set of size-$n$ subsets of some fixed set $\Omega$ of size $m$ so that you can readily compute the choice of size-$n$ subset solely from its index.
For simplicity, I will just assume $\Omega=\{0,\dots,m-1\}$ so that the states have a natural ordering to them.

With this, you can think of the set of size-$n$ subsets of $\Omega$ as length-$n$ strictly increasing sequences of numbers in $\Omega$, and you can order these lexicographically. This gives you one direction of the enumeration.
Now, we need only go backwards.

If we fix the first number of a length-$n$ increasing sequence to be $k$, then the remaining numbers have to fit in $\{k+1,\dots,m-1\}$---a set of size $m-k-1$, which means that there are ${m-k-1\choose n-1}$ length-$n$ increasing sequences which start with $k$ for any $0\leq k\leq m-1$.
This is the key for us to reverse-engineer the state from the index.
If we look at the subproblem of a length-$(n-1)$ increasing sequence of states in $\{k+1,\dots,m-1\}$, we can re-index everything by shifting down by $k+1$ and solving the recursive problem.

In summary, we can define a procedure $\def\getState{\operatorname{getState}}\getState(i,n,m,j)$ which prints the $i$th state in the lexicographical ordering of size-$n$ subsets of the set $\{j,\dots,j+m-1\}$ as follows:

- if $n=0$, quit

  > the only size-$0$ subset of a set is empty
- otherwise, let $k$ be maximal with $p := \sum_{j\leq k}{m-j-1\choose n-1}\leq i$ and print $(j+k)$

  > this finds the smallest element of the state
- recursively call $\getState(i-p, n-1, m-k-1, j+k+1)$

  > the remaining problem is to find the $(i-p)$th state in the lexicographical ordering of the size-$(n-1)$ subsets of the set $\{j+k+1,\dots,j+m-1\}$

You can use memoisation to speed up the computation of the binomial coefficients (using Pascal's triangle).

With the above procedure, the answer to your original question will be $\getState(i,n,m,0)$.